# FOSJsRoutingBundle integration with Symfony Flex

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, fosjsroutingbundle

The issue is that I cannot get **[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)** to work with **Symfony Flex** and **Webpack**.

I've been using this bundle in Symfony 3 for a long time and there's never been an issue but with the introduction of webpack, the setup has become more complex. Unfortunately the documentation for version `2.2` isn't clear.

You can find the current documentation for the bundle here: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html

As you can see it recommends the following approach for Symfony Flex, so I'm writing this in `code/assets/js/fos_js_routes.js`:

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
```

with a test route in: `code/assets/js/fos_routing_test.js`

```
Routing.generate('test_route');
```

and then including it in `webpack.config.js` as:

```
.addEntry('app_fos_routing', [
    './assets/js/fos_js_router.js'
])
.addEntry('app_fos_generate_routes', [
    './assets/js/fos_routing_test.js'
])
```

and my `code/templates/index.html.twig`:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app_fos_routing') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app_fos_generate_routes') }}
```

However when I implement this webpack creates the following which causes a reference error `ReferenceError: Routing is not defined`

```
/***/ "./assets/js/fos_js_router.js":
/*!************************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/js/fos_js_router.js ***!
  \************************************/
/*! no exports provided */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _vendor_friendsofsymfony_jsrouting_bundle_Resources_public_js_router_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js */ "./vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js");
/* harmony import */ var _vendor_friendsofsymfony_jsrouting_bundle_Resources_public_js_router_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_vendor_friendsofsymfony_jsrouting_bundle_Resources_public_js_router_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
var routes = __webpack_require__(/*! ../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json */ "./public/js/fos_js_routes.json");


_vendor_friendsofsymfony_jsrouting_bundle_Resources_public_js_router_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.setRoutingData(routes);

/***/ }),
```

Comment: I have created a new question with more detail: [Webpack FOSJsRoutingBundle integration with Symfony Flex and Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053137/webpack-fosjsroutingbundle-integration-with-symfony-flex-and-angular)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my Flex application.  Here's the steps I took to make it work:

1. Download `FOSJSRoutingBundle` and make sure that the generated file in `public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js` looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/a0d629dd944d30af120b69b96b3a8822).
2. Generate your routes with the command `fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/assets/js/fos_js_routes.json`
3. Create a JS file where you'll have to use the generated route.

test.js:

```
  import Routing from '../../../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
  const routes = require('../fos_js_routes.json'); //file with generated routes, created after executing the command above.
  Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
  Routing.generate('booking_data') //use generated route
  //... the rest of your JS code
```

Make sure that those relative paths are correct.

4. Add your test.js to your webpack.config.js file:

webpack:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .addEntry('js/test', './public/assets/js/test.js')// JAVASCRIPT
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enablePostCssLoader()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

5. Add `test.js` to your template

twig:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/test') }}
```

This is everything that I have done to make it work.

Comment: How did you do the webpack part? Can you share your front-end code please with the `js` includes?

Comment: Say the code above came from `test.js`, I just included it like this `.addEntry('js/test', './public/assets/js/test.js')` . No extra setup was needed to make it work correctly.  Here's my webpack config gist: https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/0951e598eca695d3d89b288a1c51dd8a 
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay and where does `public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js` get included in the page? This could be what I'm missing...

Comment: I didn't include that anywhere, I suppose it's used internally. Let me update my answer with more information

Comment: I wonder if it's because I have them in different `.addEntry` files, I have pretty much the same setup as you though but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your import to

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
const Routing = require('../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js');

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
```

Comment: I've obviously done that because the webpack compiles successfully when it finds the public vendor file `../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js`

Comment: sorry, I didn't see you didn't miss this step

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Same issue, looks like `Routing is defined inside the webpack function so it's unrecognised globally?

Comment: try to get the global like this: const Routing = window.Routing;